# keep log of ignored files using rsync --max-size option

Tags: rsync, logging

I'm using rsync to do some backups to an external harddrive which is formated has FAT32 so I need to ignore files bigger than 4GB, I know I can use --max-size=4GB (actually I don't know if the 4GB part is correct) but I would like to keep a log of the ignored files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't think rsync can explicitly log ignored files, but I might be wrong. 
you could always run:

```
find /src/dir -type f -size +4G > /path/to/over4gb.log
```

then you could take that log file and pass it to rsync via --exclude-from ..eg:

```
rsync -av --exclude-from=/path/to/over4g.log /src/dir/ /dest/dir/
```

just to be safe for your fat32 partition you might cut the size down to 3.8gb.. put it in a script or run it all at once:

```
find /src/dir -type f -size +3896M > /path/to/over3.8g.log && rsync -av --exclude-from=/path/to/over3.8g.log /src/dir/ /dest/dir/
```